# Different answers in forms leading to different results

Tags: javascript, forms, survey

How do you check what option you pick in two forms containing radio inputs and add points to variables depending on what option you pick?

The problem is that it only counts points from the second form (`option-6` to `option-10`) and ignores what you pick from the first form

```js
let TacoSUM = 0;
let PizzaSUM = 0;
let HamburgerSUM = 0;

function food() {
  var valueA1 = document.getElementById("option-1").checked;
  if (valueA1) {
    TacoSUM =+ 2;
    PizzaSUM =+ 1;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 0;
  }
  var valueA2 = document.getElementById("option-2").checked;
  if (valueA2) {
    TacoSUM =+ 2;
    PizzaSUM =+ 1;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 2;
  }
  var valueA3 = document.getElementById("option-3").checked;
  if (valueA3) {
    TacoSUM =+ 1;
    PizzaSUM =+ 0;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 2;
  }
  var valueA4 = document.getElementById("option-4").checked;
  if (valueA4) {
    TacoSUM =+ 0;
    PizzaSUM =+ 0;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 0;
  }
  var valueA5 = document.getElementById("option-5").checked;
  if (valueA5) {
    TacoSUM =+ 1;
    PizzaSUM =+ 2;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 0;
  }
  var valueA6 = document.getElementById("option-6").checked;
  if (valueA6) {
    TacoSUM =+ 0;
    PizzaSUM =+ 2;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 0;
  }
  var valueA7 = document.getElementById("option-7").checked;
  if (valueA7) {
    TacoSUM =+ 2;
    PizzaSUM =+ 0;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 2;
  }
  var valueA8 = document.getElementById("option-8").checked;
  if (valueA8) {
    TacoSUM =+ 0;
    PizzaSUM =+ 0;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 1;
  }
  var valueA9 = document.getElementById("option-9").checked;
  if (valueA9) {
    TacoSUM =+ 0;
    PizzaSUM =+ 2;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 0;
  }
  var valueA10 = document.getElementById("option-10").checked;
  if (valueA10) {
    TacoSUM =+ 1;
    PizzaSUM =+ 0;
    HamburgerSUM =+ 0;
  }
  alert("Taco=" + TacoSUM / 4 * 100 + "%" + " " + "Pizza=" + PizzaSUM / 4 * 100 + "%" + " " + "Hamburger=" + HamburgerSUM / 4 * 100 + "%");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <legend class="question 1 />
        <div class=" form-control ">
            <label for="option-1 ">
                <input type="radio "
                    id="option-1 "
                    value="A1 ">Fully agree</input>
            </label>
            <label for="option-2 ">
                <input type="radio "
                    id="option-2 "
                    value="A2 ">Somewhat agree</input>
            </label>
            <label for="option-3 ">
                <input type="radio "
                    id="option-3 "
                    value="A3 ">No opinion</input>
            </label>
            <label for="option-4 ">
                <input type="radio "
                    id="option-4 "
                    value="A4 ">Somewhat against</input>
            </label>
            <label for="option-5 ">
                <input type="radio "
                    id="option-5 "
                    value="A5 ">Fully against</input>
            </label>
        </form>

    <form>
            <legend class="question 2 />
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="option-6">
                <input type="radio"
                    id="option-6"
                    value="A6">Fully agree</input>
            </label>
      <label for="option-7">
                <input type="radio"
                    id="option-7"
                    value="A7">Somewhat agree</input>
            </label>
      <label for="option-8">
                <input type="radio"
                    id="option-8"
                    value="A8">No opinion</input>
            </label>
      <label for="option-9">
                <input type="radio"
                    id="option-9"
                    value="A9">Somewhat against</input>
            </label>
      <label for="option-10">
                <input type="radio"
                    id="option-10"
                    value="A10">Fully against</input>
            </label>
</form>

<button onclick="food()">DONE</button>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `food()`? It's not invoked anywhere in your sample code

Comment: you have a typo in your HTML, `<legend class="question 1</legend>` should be `<legend class="question 1" />` or `<legend class="question 1"></legend>` you made this typo twice (first and last form)

Comment: You're calling `summera()`  can you provide that function too ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).